# Host não encontra o ip do docker. Como resolver?

Tags: docker

O host é um MAC OS com o Docker instalado e com um container com php e xdebug configurado.

Tento iniciar uma sessão de debug no IntelliJ mas não está funcionando.

A minha hipótese é que já que o host não acha o container do Docker, o IDE tbm não está conseguindo achar o container. Aqui está um exemplo do funcionamento do [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote).

Quando tento fazer um ping do meu host isso é o que encontro:

1. Ip do container => `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' 64ad351e115f` //Mostra 172.17.0.2
2. Ping do container =>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Mostra perda de 100%

Como faço para expor o container?

Comment: Se não me engano, por padrão (a não ser que você tenha configurado de uma forma diferente) os containers rodam em redes isoladas do seu host, teste com: docker run -it <container-id-aqui> ping 172.17.0.2. Talvez o [expose](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) também te ajude.

Comment: Tom eu inicializo o container com -p80:80 e -p9000:9000.

Answer (score 1):

Sua máquina não vai conseguir *pingar* o ip do container, pois ele está em outra rede (isolado), o que você pode fazer é mapear as portas do container com sua máquina local. Não sei como funciona sua ferramenta de depuração, mas se ela precisa de um ip e de uma porta, você teria de fazer assim:

```
docker run --name <nome-do-container> -p 80:80 -p 9000:9000 <imagem:tag>
```

Então seu software acessaria esse container pelo seu localhost assim:

```
localhost:80 ou locahost:9000
```